# How to prevent the empty value of an int type text box

Tags: c#, winforms, integer

I have a form where I want the user to enter their first name, last name and age

But before anything, I want the user to not be able to leave the text boxes empty
The problem I have is to get the age, my data must be of type int, but I don't know how the age text box is empty and gives an error to the user.

```
string firstName = tbxName.Text;
            string lastName = tbxFamily.Text;
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(tbxAge.Text);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("لطفا نام کاربری خود را وارد کنید");
            }else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxFamily.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید");
            }else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxAge.Text)) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("لطفا سن خود را بررسی کنید");
            }else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" نام کاربری " + firstName + " نام خانوادگی " + lastName + " با سن " + age + " با موفقیت ثبت شد ");
            }
```

Comment: so, what's wrong with your code ?

Comment: ```IsNullOrEmpty(tbxAge.Text)```, if false, so ```int age = Convert.ToInt32(tbxAge.Text)```

Comment: If the user needs to input a _number_, you should use an appropriate UI Component for exactly that, not a _text_ box.

Comment: Maybe, it would also be interesting for you to read about [input validation in winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
        string firstName = textBox1.Text;
        string lastName = textBox2.Text;
        int age;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("لطفا نام کاربری خود را وارد کنید");
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید");
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("لطفا سن خود را بررسی کنید");

        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            if (textBox3.Text.All(char.IsDigit))
            {
                age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("لطفا سن خود را بررسی کنید");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" نام کاربری " + firstName + " نام خانوادگی " + lastName + " با سن " + age + " با موفقیت ثبت شد ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To awnser the title qeustion (assuming an "int type text box" is just a [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)):

```
int num = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(textBox1);
```

This uses the [ternary operator '?'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Be carfull Convert.ToInt32 can throw a exception if it can't convert.
Use int.TryParse() instead

Comment: Thanks guys
I used another method
First, I wrote the age as a string in the conditional IF statement so that the text box is not empty
Now I converted it to int data to display the output